# Mixing regex and shell wildcards

Tags: python, regex, wildcard

I have a python script that reads from a config file. The config file is going to contain some user defined regex patterns. However, I was thinking I'd like to let the user use either full regex patterns, OR shell wildcards. So I should be able to interpret both

`*.txt`
as well as
`.*\.txt$`
correctly. So those 2 should be equivalent.

However I'd like to be able to do this without making the user tell me which they're using. Is this even possible? Maybe allowing full regex is overkill.

Comment: I don't think you can determine unambiguously what a given pattern is. Even though in this case the first pattern is not a valid regex, how could you tell if it's a "shell wildcard" or an invalid (mistyped) regex?

Comment: That's exactly why I'm asking the question, I don't know if it's possible =]

Comment: Some shells (at least zsh) let you mix these things quite freely and still (usually) do the right thing. As NullUserException says: unambiguously, no.

Comment: The problem is I'm not sure if a string can be a valid regex AND a valid wildcard set. If not, I can just try it as a regex and if it fails it's a shell wildcard and I can just leave it up to the user to input it correctly

Comment: You could split the config file in two parts, where you use regex in one, and the users only use shell wildcards in the other. IMHO, that would be the cleanest solution and wouldn't lead to issues like 'Why doesn't `index.*` do what I want?'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this.  What should `prefix.*` match?  What about `somefiles?`? These have very different meanings in regex vs glob matching, but are common use cases in both.

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach could be:

1. Try to compile the given expression as a regex.

   a. If this fails (syntax error), use the expression as a glob string.

   b. If it doesn't fail to compile, use it as a regex.
2. If it doesn't match anything, use it as a glob string.

In any case, tell the user what you did ("Interpreting `pattern.*` as a regular expression") and allow him to override whatever you have guessed. After all, as Zak Thompson wrote, some patterns will be both valid regexes and glob patterns.

Another thing to take into consideration is that a user can easily overload or crash your system with a regex through [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html). So unless it's your user's own machine, you might want to think about allowing regexes in the first place.

Comment: Yeah this will be running on the user's personal machine

Answer (score 0):

Consider, for example, the pattern

```
foo?.txt
```

In glob-syntax, this will match foo1.txt, fooZ.txt but not fo.txt, fob.txt or fooZtxt
In regexp syntaxt, this will match fo.txt, foQtxt, but not fooZ.txt

You can't, unambiguously, accept both syntaxes. The only option I can think of is have the user prefix the expression, i.e.

```
regexp:foo?.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Try not to leave the creation of regex to the user. The user should have an easier means to configure their files without needing to use regex. Eg  let the users have a few choices,

1. starts with
2. ends with
3. contains (OR and AND)
4. etc

Then as the programmer, you use these choices to construct your regex.

Comment: That's sort of why I'm trying to use both. I'm going to be using this program personally as well, in fact I'm mostly writing it for myself. So I'd like to support regex matches.